# No boxing or type parameter conversion error

Tags: c#, sqlite, generics, xamarin.forms

I have a mobile PCL project using Xamarin.Forms. In the PCL I have my various SQLite classes and an SQLite database helper class (called `DBManager`). In the platform parts, I create the instance to the Database (as it uses the file system which is not supported in PCL). The instance has an interface to get the connection string and the connection.

The interface to the platform part is called `IDatabaseConnection`.

Each of my Sqlite classes has an interface to it called `IDatabase`. This allows me to create a set of generic methods using properties I know are in the classes like this

```
    public static List<T> GetListOfObjects<T>() where T:IDatabase, new()
    {
        var data = App.Singleton.DBManager.GetListOfObjects<T>();
        return data.ToList();
    }
```

I've used the class plenty of times in non-PCL projects and I know this works fine.

The problem is that I'm getting the following error

`The type 'T' cannot be used as type parameter 'T' in the generic type or method 'MyMobileApp.DBManager.GetListOfObjects<T>()'. There is no boxing or type parameter conversion from 'T' to 'MyMobileApp.IDatabaseConnection'`

is this down to the DBManager in the non-PCL part using `IDatabaseConnection` and if it is, is there a solution so that I can still use my generic helper class methods?

Comment: It's not really clear where the PCL part is relevant here - presumably `IDatabase` doesn't implement `IDatabaseConnection`, but `DBManager.GetListOfObjects()` requires a `T` that implements `IDatabaseConnection`... (Somewhat odd interface names, to be honest...)

Comment: DBManager implements IDatabaseConnection, the SQLite classes implement IDatabase. The SQLite classes and majority of the DBManager are in the PCL project but as there is limited file system support in PCL, this is farmed out to the platform specific code

Comment: Look at the error message - you haven't shown us the declaration of `GetListOfObjects`, but given the error message it seems reasonably clear that `T` has to implement `IDatabaseConnection`. It would be a lot easier to help you if you'd post all the relevant signatures though...

Comment: The method you show takes in IDatabase, but the error is saying the method you are trying to call expects IDatabaseConnection.